# javascript set property in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to set the property(p1) of an item in an array.
For example, array[1].p1="David". But an error happened.
Following is the code, could someone give me a hint?Many thanks.

```
    var array1=new Array();         

        array1[0].p1="MARY";
        array1[1].p1="JHON";
        for (index = 0; index < array1.length; ++index) {
            alert(array1[index].p1);            
        }
```

I`ve tried array1.push({p1:"MARY"}), it works! But it can not set the value by "particular" index.

Comment: `array1[0] = {p1: "MARY"}`. `array1[0]` does not exist before you insert it, so trying to set its `p1` property individually makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any method that could check first whether array1[0].p1 is exist before I set the value?

Comment: I interpret what you wrote as "is there any method to check whether `array1[0]` has a property `p1`, assuming that `array1[0]` itself is an object?". Was that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do in your first example is add a property to an non-existent object in the first element slot of the array. This is why there's an error.

This is why your second example works. The object `{p1:"MARY"}` itself is being pushed into the first position. As Jon says in the comments this can also be done using `array1[0] = {p1: "MARY"}`.

(In your example, make sure you `var` your loop variables):

```
var array1 = new Array();
array1[0] = {p1: 'MARY'};
array1[1] = {p1: "JHON"};

for (var index = 0; index < array1.length; ++index) {
  console.log(array1[index].p1); // MARY, JHON
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL7nc/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You asssumed that array is filled with empty objects `{}` by default which is not true. Before `array1[0].properties` you must place there object (hashmap):
`array1[0] = {}`.

Answer (score 1):

Array should be declared as an object

for e.g.
    a[0] = {"p1":"Mary"}

Answer (score 1):

```
myObject["123"] = { "C": 123, "D": 456 };
```

does not add more elements to the object (associative array), it replaces them; to add elements you'd have to write:

```
myObject["123"].C =123;
myObject["123"].D = 456;
```

As for #2 and #3, Javascript objects do not guarantee to return properties in the order in which they were added; for this you would have to resort to an array, and then after adjusting your data to the strictures of the different data structure, you could get the first element with:

```
myArray.shift()
```